# Getting mySQL date_format to display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

This could sound like a very simple question to many of you, but I seem to be having trouble getting a basic date_format to work with my mySQL statement and then to be displayed using php. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT('timestamp', '%W %D %M %Y') as date FROM articleDB WHERE userID='".$_SESSION["**"]."' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 8");
```

Then trying to display it using:

```
echo ' Posted: '.$row['timestamp'].'';
```

All I want is to format the date from a PHP myAdmin timestamp to the format I want.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use backticks ( `` `) or nothing at all instead of single-quotes (`'`) around your field in your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%W %D %M %Y') as date FROM articleDB WHERE userID='".$_SESSION["**"]."' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 8");
```

Backticks ( `` `) creates a reference to a table member, single-quotes creates a string (`'`). You were basically trying to`DATE_FORMAT`the string`'timestamp'` instead of the field.

Also, since you are using `as` to create a field alias, you want to refer to that field using the alias when outputting:

```
echo ' Posted: '.$row['date'];
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to display the "date" column that you calculate/format in the select statement, the timestamp column contains the unformatted original date value.

```
echo ' Posted: '.$row['date'];
```

Answer (score 0):

since in your SQL query you define the date formatting `as date` you access it by `$row['date']`.